# Rounded Bar Charts using - ApexCharts

Tags: reactjs

Using 'apex charts' bar chart..

All parts should be round, but the beginning is not round. What's the problem?

I've used a lot of options, but I can't solve them.

I need help...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoliK.jpg)

```
<ApexCharts type="bar"                        
                        width="100%"
                        height="150px"
                        series={[{
                            data: [400, 353, 300, 220, 127]
                        },
                        ]}
                        options={{
                            chart: {
                                type: 'bar',
                                fontFamily: 'Noto Sans KR',
                                redrawOnParentResize: true,
                                sparkline: {
                                    enabled: true
                                }
                            },
                            plotOptions: {
                                bar: {
                                    borderRadius: 4,
                                    distributed: true,
                                    horizontal: true,
                                    barHeight: '82%',
                                    dataLabels: {
                                        position: 'top',
                                    },
                                },
                            },
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                textAnchor: 'start',
                                distributed: true,
                                offsetX: 22,
                                style: {
                                    fontSize: '15px',
                                    fontWeight: '400',
                                    colors: ['#000']
                                }
                            },
                            fill: {
                                colors: ['#B20048', '#E6553D', '#F5BA46', '#88C053', '#35BA9B'],
                                opacity: 1,
                            },             
                        }}>
            </ApexCharts>
```

Comment: Increase the `borderRadius` should help. [Example](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/column-charts/column-with-data-labels/)